# Neo4j Node Visualization

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-visualization, grass-file

In Neo4j, using .grass-style files to set the appearance of nodes and relationships, how can one pick a certain style for a node with multiple labels?

Since .grass-files define the visual style of a graph item by linking a certain label to a certain style the obvious question arises:

**How to deal with a graph item with multiple labels?**

Say, I have the following:

.grass file (pseudo-syntax):

```
for label "User" use color=red
for label "computer" use color=blue
```

graph (abstracted):

```
node John has Label "user"
node Mac has Label "computer"
node Robot has Labels "user" and "computer"
```

This obviously colors nodes John and Mike red and blue respectively.

But what about the node Robot?

*In my particular problem I have a number of nodes with 2 labels each. One of these 2 labels, LabelA is common among all nodes and the other one differs from node to node. What I want is, to use the .grass style of the other-labels-style for my nodes - what it does is, i uses LabelA for all nodes to style them.*

After strugeling with this issue for quite some time I give up.

Does anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to my question but it is a work-around that finally helped me and might also help other people out there.

Assuming I have all relevant styles defined in a .grass files (one for each label) I simply post-process my graph once it is loaded in my Neo4j browser.

This means, that I delete all those labels from my nodes which are blocking the style I need for the nodes leaving only this single label which gives me my required style.

Sure, this is quite unhandy and not optimal but it's the only attempt I found.

I will not mark this as answer since maybe someone will have a more appropriate idea ...